# EF 5: Each property name in a type must be unique error

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first

I try to migrate from EDMX to CodeFirst. And I write some code, that you can see below.
When I try to get some data from context, I receive an error:

---

(10,6) : Error 0019: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name "Value" already defined.

---

But I need Value property in a few classes. And in ObjectContext + EDMX it works.
How can I properly configure that?
Thank you.

```
public abstract class Test
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
    public class Test1:Test
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string Prim { get; set; }
    }
    public class Test2 : Test
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
    public class TestContext : BaseDbContext, IContext
    {
        public TestContext()
            : base("name=TestContext")
        {

        }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Test> TestData { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TestConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Test1Configuration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Test2Configuration());
        }
    }
    public class TestConfiguration : System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<Test>
    {
        public TestConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("Test");
            HasKey(x => x.ID);
            Map<Test1>(m =>
            {
                m.Requires("Type").HasValue(1);
            })
                .Map<Test2>(m =>
                {
                    m.Requires("Type").HasValue(2);
                });

        }
    }
    public class Test1Configuration : System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<Test1>
    {
        public Test1Configuration()
        {
            Property(x => x.Prim).HasColumnName("Prim");
            Property(x => x.Value).HasColumnName("Value");
        }
    }
    public class Test2Configuration : System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<Test2>
    {
        public Test2Configuration()
        {
            Property(x => x.Value).HasColumnName("Value");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found that is not supported in EF5, but will be supported in EF 6. What a pity...